# Socket.io and server-side webpack bundling

Tags: node.js, webpack, socket.io

In web project server side/backend is packed and bundled by `webpack` in `node mode` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/) to achieve one independent bundled distributed file, like for client/frontend side.

But there is one problem: that project is dependent on `Socket.io` library, and server-side part of `socket.io` contains following line: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L110 , which implies load some library part at runtime.
Such behavior causes problems in bundling server side by `webpack`, because socket.io-client library is not required directly by require operation, and that's why does not compile into bundle.

Of course, it's potentially possible to develop own `Webpack plugin`, which will search and operate over `require.resolve` invocations, for example, by resolving target files and place them in memory file system or pack into bundle as resources. But it not simple manual work, and most probably well-known solution is exists.

For example, maybe is there already bundled version of library for webpack usage?

Comment: You could also instruct the SocketIO server to [disable serving the client](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/##server) and serve it "manually".